# Unable to directly concat arrays in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular, I'm trying to merge two arrays, both matching a basic interface, but not exactly the same:

```
export const orgAdminRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        resolve: {
            org: OrgResolver
        },
        canActivate: [
            AdminGuard
        ],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'users',
                component: UsersComponent
            }
        ]
    },
];

let orgChildren: Route[] = [
    {
        path: 'events',
        component: EventsListComponent,
    },
];
```

I want to join the two arrays, but was hoping to just make `orgChildren` the final variable, so tried:

```
let orgChildren: Route[] = [
    {
        path: 'events',
        component: EventsListComponent,
    },
].concat(orgAdminRoutes);
```

Which throws this error:

```
'Argument of type 'Route[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ path: string; component: typeof EventsListComponent; } | { path: string; component: typeof Even...'.
  Type 'Route[]' is not assignable to type '{ path: string; component: typeof EventsListComponent; }[]'.
    Type 'Route' is not assignable to type '{ path: string; component: typeof EventsListComponent; }'.
      Property 'path' is optional in type 'Route' but required in type '{ path: string; component: typeof EventsListComponent; }'.'
```

If I just create both separately, then concat them after (`orgChildren.concat(orgAdminRoutes)` later in the code), it works fine, but I don't understand why and am hoping someone might know?

Comment: Why not use the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) `...` operator? You are using Typescript afterall.

Comment: @NeilLunn The spread operator worked great, and I'll look more into it's uses. I am hoping someone can help me understand why this bit of typescript failed, just so I can improve my knowledge there too. Thanks for a better coding technique though!

Answer (score 0):

So I may be wrong, but I think what's happening is that in

```
let orgChildren: Route[] = [
    {
        path: 'events',
        component: EventsListComponent,
    },
].concat(orgAdminRoutes);
```

My assumption was that the array I'm defining would be typed as `Route[]`, but that happens after it's assigned. So when I concat, I'm concating an array with types in it, which don't match the `Route[]` type. I guess I could do some fun typecasting tricks to get it to fit in one line, but maybe two is better.